# Can someone clarify why the value of a variable in my loop is not updating until the loop is closed?

Tags: ruby, loops, integer-division

This is my function

```
def rating(array)
  sum_count = array.values.inject(0) { |sum_count,value| sum_count + value }
  run_count = 0
  array.each do |tag,count|
    run_count += count
    cum_distn = run_count/sum_count
    logger.debug "cum_distn is #{cum_distn.to_f}; run_count is #{run_count.to_f}; sum_count is #{sum_count}"
    if cum_distn < 0.25
      ...
    elsif cum_distn < 0.5
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

For 2 objects in my array with counts of 1 each, my logger is showing this:

```
cum_distn is 0.0; run_count is 1.0; sum_count is 2
cum_distn is 1.0; run_count is 2.0; sum_count is 2
```

It seems that the value of cum_distn is only updating once one loop is complete whilst I intend for it to update immediately before the if function opens. I have two questions:

(a) Why is this happening (as I can't see any logical explanation)?

(b) How can I rectify this to do what I want?

Comment: Not yet finished reading your question but you should replace `def rating(array)` by `def rating(hash)` because `hash.values` makes more sense than `array.values`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using integer division, so the result of `run_count / sum_count` gets truncated. To fix, simply convert one of them to `Float` before calculating `cum_distn`. For example:

```
cum_distn = run_count.to_f / sum_count
```

Answer (score 2):

1) It happens because `3/2 #=> 1` but `3.0/2 # => 1.5`. In other terms, `integer/integer #=> integer` and `float/integer #=> float`

2) Just call `to_f` one time, at the beginning (not in a loop because it's really not performant):

```
def rating(hash)
  sum_count = hash.values.inject(:+).to_f
  hash.inject(0) do |run_count, (tag, count)|
    run_count += count
    cum_dist = run_count/sum_count
    logger.debug "cum_distn is #{cum_distn}; run_count is #{run_count}; sum_count is #{sum_count}"
    ...
    run_count # return run_count
  end
end
```